# Autofilter/Delete VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Have a VBA code autofilter and delete filtered rows. Code below:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveCell.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(6, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I have this code working on 3-5 sheets. The first 2 sheets work with no issues. The third sheet is where I have issues. My columns headers start in row6, I am filtering by column 9. Basically column 9 has a formula where if A1 = "","True", ""). I filter to the cells that don't have any text in column 9. For sheet 3, I should only have 4 rows of data. When the first line of filtering kicks in, it filters correctl and shows rows 11 and beyond. When the deleting line of code kicks in it skips deleting row 11 and starts deleting at row 12 and beyond. I am not sure what is going on as it works fine on the first 2 sheets. I have looked to see if row 11 had any different cell formats, etc.. and haven't found a reason for this issue.

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Re _it skips deleting row 11 and starts deleting at row 12 and beyond_, that beacuse you told it to with `.Offset(6, 0)` (HeDER ROW IN ROW 6, +6 rows offset = start at row 12).  Should be `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete` (Offset 1 to avoid deleting the header row)